# Does each verb have a corresponding noun with the same meaning

Tags: semantics, verbs, nouns

I believe that each main verb has (at least) one corresponding noun with the same meaning that is formed from gerund and derivation. For examples, *discovery* is from *discover*; *reading* is from *read*; *addition* is from *add*; and simply zero derivation like *love* for *love*.

The converse is not true, i.e. nouns generally do not have verbs with the same meaning. I'd like this to be verified. Any thought is welcome.

Comment: You can always use the present participle of a verb as a kind of noun: _Running/Swimming/Reading maths is a lot of fun_. But there is no corresponding inflectional form of nouns that verbs them; however, zero derivation is very common, like _Verbing nouns weirds language_.

Comment: I don't share JL's views. The first two of his examples are strictly speaking ambiguous, but verb preferred: "to run/swim is fun". Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "Occasional running/swimming is fun". His third example, however, is not ambiguous: it can only be **verb** since it has the direct object "maths".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This was revised after some great feedback.)*

Your assertion is largely true, but not universally true.

Strong candidates:

- modal verbs (could, should, ...),
- compound verbs (spread-eagle, roll-in-the-hay, ...),

There are also tricky ones like 'manhandling' where many dictionaries won't recognize a noun variant, while others will.

Comment: *being,having, sponging-off, hunkering-down, eagle-spreading, rolling-in the-hay*. No gerund for *could*, and other preterit forms, but for the perfect, *having could*. All these nouns fit *my <noun>*. You may argue they're still verb like, and I'd argue that half of them were adverbial, because they can never stand without a finite verb that they modify. In fact, since *sponge. spread* (or *eagle*), and *roll* are nouns, they don't need to nominalize anymore. Bam! What a shake-down. Sorry for my butt-in, but's a real butt-kick. Maybe it appears easier to me,.an L2 learner. than it really is.

Comment: @Vectory: I accept some of yours, but not "eagle-spreading". I **might** be able to guess by context what you meant by "He was eagle-spreading on the floor", but I'm not sure that I would. It simply does not exist as a nominalisation - probably because _spread_ in the original phrase is not a verb base but a past participle (not a noun). I don't know what you meant by _having could_: it's not grammatical in any version of English that I recognise.

Comment: @ColinFine I've never heard *eagle-spread* in context, I just know what it means because German has similarly *den Adler machen*, "to do the eagle". Your "He was eagle-spreading" would be a past continuous, if an active verb, or, more importantly, a passive past participle. I was rather thinking of "Your <gerund> is ...". For *could*, I messed up badly. There is no past perfect of *can* that I know of, I was thinking of "could have" instead. At best there is a paradigm, in which "ability" is the noun to *can*, and e.g. *potential* to *could*, just like *be*, *am*, *exist* have different roots.

Comment: Never the less, *your having missed* my allusion to phrases like this here is perhaps more telling of my appropriation of the English language, but I did not make it up. Searching "your having could", I'm met with loads of cases where "your"="you're". So much for appropriation.

Comment: This answer is wrong regarding auxiliary and phrasal verbs (they both have gerund forms); modals should not even be called verbs; and the compound verbs seem to depend on whether they use a verb or a participle.

Comment: I agree with many of the comments and will attempt to sort them out.

Comment: @vectory: Infinitives for modals are one of the reasons there are periphrastic modals: _having been able to_ works where *_having could_ doesn't.